# Как сохранить ссылку на элемент массива

Tags: android, kotlin

Заранее извиняюсь, если неправильно сформировал вопрос.

Задача такая. Есть два массива. M1 и M2. Пользователь где-то в настройках выбрал, что его интересует значение M1[44] (к примеру). Далее я запоминаю этот выбор, и в дальнейшем на activity вывожу периодически значение сохранённого выбора. Значение в M1[44] меняется постоянно.

Т.е. примерно так:

```
val mass1 = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val mass2 = arrayOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
// запоминаем выбор
val selectedValue = mass1[2]

// в activity выводим 
text1.setText(selectedValue.toString) //к примеру
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `// в activity выводим 
text1.setText(mass1[selectedIndex].toString) //к примеру
`

Comment: В (kotlin-)java нет указателей - поэтому вы можете ссылаться на ячейку массива только через сам массив по индексу.

Comment: А если выбран второй массив?

Comment: Так значение или массив? Поясните подробнее что вы хотите - сейчас ничего не понятно, что выбирает пользователь, что нужно отобразить...

Comment: Пользователь выбирает одно из значений, которые хранятся в двух массивах. У меня это 1 массив - данные по автомобилю общие, 2 массив - данные по двигателю. Он например хочет видеть на экране обороты. Выбирает их. Вот мне надо их выводить на экран, на основе его выбора. Откуда он выберет и что выберет, мне не известно

Comment: Тогда нужно запомнить и массив, и индекс ячейки. Либо сделать дата-класс, в котором хранить и менять значение, массивы заполнить его экземплярами - тогда вы можете взять на него ссылку и выводить значение по вашему варианту.

Comment: Наверное так и придётся, думал обойтись малой кровью

Comment: Сделайте 1 массив не из простых типов а объектный, типа Integer, ссылку на объект получаете через индекс массива и передаете во 2 активность, но здесь нужно использовать статические переменные иначе к примеру при повороте Активность родитель будет уничтожена вместе с массивами.

Comment: @Style-7, 1) обёртки типа `Integer` никак не помогут - они неизменяемые. Вы в массив будете записывать другой `Integer`, а полученный ранее никогда не изменится. Автору нужно отображать актуальное значение, а не то что было на момент выбора. 2) Код не должен полагаться на существование каких либо активностей, кроме той что в данный момент на переднем плане. Другие могут быть прибиты системой в любой момент для освобождения памяти.

Comment: @woesss я вас понял, я подзабыл что это класс final, но можно создать свой, согласитесь вариант.

Comment: @Style-7, конечно соглашусь - я сам предложил этот вариант ^выше^.

Comment: Можно использовать MutableInt из org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable. [Подключение.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835143/how-to-add-org-apache-commons-lang3-to-androidstudio-with-gradle)

Comment: Спасибо всем, делаю через массив, содержащий номера вхождений и выбор массива, и далее через when